# ubuntu 12 not loading after reboot

Tags: 12.04, boot

I rebooted my computer that has ubuntu 12.04 installed, but the operating system is not loading any more.

The screen is completely blank and the computer is turned on.

Why could this happen?

Comment: Is your problem similar to [this](/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) or to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the power button to force shutdown, after try booting again if you get n option to go to advanced ubuntu settings click it (recovery) then repair broken files or resume boot and try some stuff